# Level variables along with differenced variables in ARDL / Error Correctional Model

Tags: ecm, ardl

I am running an ARDL model, I have both levels and difference variables. I know for sure that the difference variables should be included in the ECM but should I include the level variables as well?

Comment: See Dave Giles' blog post ["ARDL Models - Part II - Bounds Tests"](http://davegiles.blogspot.no/2013/06/ardl-models-part-ii-bounds-tests.html).

Comment: So is it ARDL, ECM or some hybrid?